# Conflict on ng-view while loading materialize javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, materialize

I have the following layout page:

```
<body scroll-spy="" class="theme-template-dark theme-amber alert-open alert-with-mat-grow-top-right solar-custom">
    <main>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main-content" autoscroll="true" bs-affix-target="" init-ripples="">
                <section class="forms-basic">
                    <div ng-view class="view-animate view-fade">
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

I have an ng-view here in order to get html files on my code and place it's content inside here.
The problem I noticed is the following:
I have various textboxes from materialize which all should have an animation that kicks in on focus and blur.

[image]
[image]

However, I noticed that this animation does not occur on elements inside an ng-view.

One thing I noticed that there is a function on an js file that runs when the page loads.

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(), $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(), $(".navbar-toggle").sideNav({
        menuWidth: 260, closeOnClick: !0
    }
    );
    var a = [".btn:not(.withoutripple)", ".card-image", ".navbar a:not(.withoutripple)", ".dropdown-menu a", ".nav-tabs a:not(.withoutripple)", ".withripple"].join(",");
    $("body").find(a).ripples(), $(".form-control").each(function () {
        $(this).val() && $(this).parent().addClass("filled"), $(this).bind("blur", function (a) {
            input = $(a.currentTarget), input.val() ? input.parent().addClass("filled") : input.parent().removeClass("filled"), input.parent().removeClass("active")
        }
        ).bind("focus", function (a) {
            input = $(a.currentTarget), input.parent().addClass("active")
        }
        )
    }
    )
}
```

That code runs smoothly on load, and also when I click on a textbox that is on the main page (not in this example). BUT, if I add an input on the html that will be used as an ng-view, it does not run, which leads me to believe that when the js file runs, the ng-view is not rendered yet.

So, is there a way that I can get the ng-views to read all of materialize properties and not have these kinds of issues?